# Regex to replace colon in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
let str = '/user/:username/'
```

I want to extract replace `username` with `harry` with colon removed.

I tried the following:

```
const regex = /[^:]+(?=:)/g
str.replace(regex, x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `/:\w+/`

```
let str = '/user/:username/'
str.replace(/:\w+/, "harry")
// => "/user/harry/"
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = '/user/:username/';
let html = str.replace(":username", "harry");
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '/user/:username/';
var newstr = str.replace(/:username/i, "harry");
print(newstr);
```

hi pal, is this what you are looking for? i found it at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: `i` flag seems to be unnecessary

Comment: hi mrzasa, true dat /i.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like that :

```
let str = '/user/:username/';
str.replace(':username','harry')
// o/p => /user/harry/"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your regex `[^:]+(?=:)` you are matching 1+ times not a colon and assert that at the end there should be a colon resulting in a match for `/user/`

If you want to use the negated character class you could match a colon and then not a forward slash:

```
:[^\/]+
```

```js
const str = `/user/:username/`;
const result = str.replace(/:[^\/]+/, "harry");
console.log(result);
```